# Android application for mirroring screen to PC, does not need internet

Tags: android, screen-sharing

I'm looking for an Android app which has the same functionality as [Mobizen](https://www.mobizen.com/) that will allow me to control the phone's display directly via the windows PC.

The reason why I cannot use Mobizen is because Mobizen requires the PC and Android phone to be connected to the internet. Is there an alternative app I can use?

Comment: my name is Ben. Does the MyMobiler app you're talking about, use Wi-Fi signal but not internet, even if you are connected to internet via WiFi at the time?

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options, I personally would recommend MyMobiler,

**[MyMobiler for Android](http://mymobiler.com/android.html)**
The MyMobiler desktop application controls your Android device through USB connection or WiFi. It allows you to see your mobile device remotely and capture the screen or video. What you see in the desktop application is mirroring your device screen and you can interact with your device using the mouse and keyboard.

[image: MyMobiler Demo Screen on PC]

- Control your device using your desktop keyboard and mouse.
- Capture the screen and video.
- Copy/Cut/Paste text between device and desktop.
- Transfer files between device and desktop.
- **USB** / WiFi Connection.
- Android OS version 2.2 or later.

**[Air Droid 3](https://www.airdroid.com/)**
AirMirror, a way of interacting between PC/Mac and your Android. Your Android, right on your computer, right now.
[image: AirDroid 3 with AirMirror on PC]